# Surface gradient of a vector field

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, vector-fields

Let $\mathbb{M} \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ be a $C^2$ manifold with normal vector ${\bf n}$. Then, for any scalar-valued function $f$, we can write its *surface gradient* as:
\begin{align}
\nabla_{\mathbb{M}} f = \left(I-{\bf n}{\bf n}^T\right)\nabla f,
\end{align}
where $\nabla$ is the $\mathbb{R}^3$ gradient (treated here as a column vector). Clearly, $P = \left(I-{\bf n}{\bf n}^T\right)$ is a projection operator onto the tangent plane.

Let ${\bf u} = [u,v,w]^T$ be a vector field in $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that ${\bf u} \cdot {\bf n} = 0$, in other words, ${\bf u}$ is tangent to $\mathbb{M}$, but has 3 components. It is common in mechanics (and other applications) to define the *gradient* of this vector field as
\begin{align}
\nabla {\bf u} = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial u}{\partial z} \\
\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial v}{\partial z} \\
\frac{\partial w}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial w}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial w}{\partial z} 
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}
My question is, what is the *surface gradient* of ${\bf u}$ if ${\bf u} \cdot {\bf n} = 0$? Is it simply the following?
\begin{align}
\nabla_{\mathbb{M}} {\bf u} = P \nabla {\bf u}.
\end{align}
If not, what is the correct expression?

I'd appreciate an answer in terms of these $\mathbb{R}^3$ operators rather than intrinsic derivatives. Also, a symbolic expression for $\nabla_{\mathbb{M}} {\bf u}$ would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Literally: This definition of "surface gradient" is made only for scalar functions. To ask about gradients of vector fields, we need a definition of _surface gradient_ for a vector field. <> The natural definition looks like the matrix whose rows are the surface gradients of the components of $\mathbf{u}$; if I'm not mistaken (I haven't carefully checked the row/column conventions), your proposed formula is correct whether or not $\mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{n} = 0$.

Comment: Hm, okay. Thanks. If you make this an answer, I can mark it as such :)

Comment: Actually, @AndrewD.Hwang, as a counterexample, see Eq. 2.1. https://www.igpm.rwth-aachen.de/Download/reports/pdf/IGPM512.pdf. For some reason, they have an extra projection in there.

Comment: Ah...that shows my naive definition was "wrong". Given the definition of a surface gradient of a vector field in the linked paper, your formula is correct under the stated conditions because $\mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{n} = 0$ if and only if $P\mathbf{u} = \mathbf{u}$. :)

Comment: This chat is helping. You're saying the extra projection basically knocks out the part of $P \nabla {\bf u}$ in the normal direction? And the post-multiplication is because of the gradients forming the rows of the matrix, rather than the columns?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Sorry to bug you, but I'm still stuck here. I'm still not sure whether my formula is correct or not, and I'm not able to see why it should be if $u.n=0$.

Comment: My oops at letting this drop. <> On closer look, I'm not sure I understand the second equation (2.1) in the linked article. I'd understood they meant to take a vector field on $M$, project away the normal component, extend to a neighborhood and take the gradient, then project away the normal component of the gradient, but that's not what's written in the article. Is the procedure outlined here consistent with your understanding of the engineering context?

Comment: You know, what you described would make way more sense, but that's definitely not what they're doing. My experience in the engineering context is purely for scalar functions, so I'm struggling for the vector version. For vectors tangential to the surface, I frankly am not seeing why one couldn't just compute the gradient componentwise in the neighborhood, then project each component.

Comment: Agreed entirely about component functions; that would be consistent with how we compute covariant derivatives in the differential geometry of surfaces. <> What currently doesn't make sense to me (not just mathematical sense, but syntactic sense) is the putative definition $$
\nabla_{M} \mathbf{u}(x) = \mathbf{P}(x) \nabla\mathbf{u}^{e}(x) \mathbf{P}(x),
$$which is supposed to act on a vector field $\mathbf{u}$, but then there's that  $\mathbf{u}^{e}$ between the application of projection operators. Maybe contact the authors, if that's feasible?

Comment: I think I will have to contact the authors. I can see why the "post" projection is done if the gradient of each component is a row of the grad u matrix, but I don't see why the "pre" projection is needed. $u^e$ is just their way of saying the vector field is defined in a tubular neighborhood around the manifold.